# Capacitor App Plugin dont let android studio build the apk

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am following the tutorial here: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app
I did the following steps:

- pnpm install @capacitor/app
- npx cap sync
- added the code below inside the activity section of the AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
  ```
- pnpm react-scripts build && npx cap sync android && npx cap copy android && npx cap open android

I always did it that way, and it always build the apk normally, but just when I add the Capacitor APP plugin, the android studio gives an error

[android studio bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwDTh.png)

I didn't even change the code, I just added the plugin by pnpm install @capacitor/app and npx cap sync

Has anyone ever experienced this? Do you have any ideas on how to proceed?

solutions I tried:

- install java sdk 17
- delete the android folder and do npx cap add android && npx cap sync pnpm react-scripts build && npx cap sync android && npx cap copy android && npx cap open android

I expected to compile the app/apk normally, I'm trying to use the backButton event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I am using pnpm, it downloaded version 5 of @capacitor/app, and my capacitor was on version 4.7.1, they are incompatible, I downgraded @capacitor/app to 4.1.1 and everything was resolved.

Another thing, in the official tutorial it says to add those 4 lines, but when installing the app, there's no way to open it and it doesn't appear in the list of apps on the phone, so I had to remove the 4 lines

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).